# friendly_id slug is not generating on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I have an active record callback on my user model to generate a username if the user didn't specify a username. This would occur when the user would register via Google, Facebook, or any other third party.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

  before_validation :set_default_username 

  private

    def set_default_username
      self.username ||= "user#{User.last.id+1}"
    end

end
```

The problem is, in my seeds file, i noticed for one of my users, the slug was not being created, specifically on this case:

```
User.create(email:"nousername@outlook.com", password: "password")
```

While the username is being created due to set_default_username, the slug is not being created. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try with `before_save` callback

Comment: nope, doesn't work. I've tried it with before_save, before_create, before_validation; nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @rich-peck I was able to figure out the solution to this problem after reading the source code of friendly_id. The root of the problem was that [friendly_id uses a before_validation](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb#L212) to set the slug.

In order to fix my problem, I had to set my model as following.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId 

  before_validation :set_default_username

  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable

  private

    def set_default_username
      self.username ||= "user#{User.maximum(:id).next}"
    end

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      slug.blank? || username_changed?
    end
  end
```

Comment: You did submit and accept an own answer even though your answer is mostly based on what @rich-peck suggested. You might consider accepting his answer and at least give him an up-vote if it did contribute to your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's a `friendly_id` issue:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

  before_save :set_default_username 

  private

    def set_default_username
      self.username ||= "user#{User.maximum(:id).next}"
    end

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      slug.blank? || username_changed?
    end

end
```

A resource for you: [Ruby on Rails: How to get ActiveRecord to show the next id (last + 1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755622/ruby-on-rails-how-to-get-activerecord-to-show-the-next-id-last-1)

Comment: thank you for that resource, as you might have noticed, I am fairly new to ruby. On another note, the slug is now being generated, but it's giving something completely useless. upon creation of a user where the username isn't set, the slug is -43f79fd3-57c2-4170-a677-769018bf92b1

Comment: That's a UID. They're automatically generated in the event that the slug being created is a duplicate.