# Fill form with two values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have user/registrations/new.html.haml

```
- title 'User Registration'

.vcentered  .signup-box
  - if @user.authorizations.any?    %h1 We just need a little more information...
  - else    %h1 We just need a little bit of information...

  = form_for @user, url: user_registration_path, html: { class: 'new-user form-default' } do |f|
   - if @user.name.blank?
    = f.text_field :name, class: class_with_errors(@user, :name),
                          title: title_with_errors(@user, :name),
                          placeholder: 'Full Name'

   - if @user.email.blank? || @user.errors.any?
    = f.text_field :email, class: class_with_errors(@user, :email),
                           title: title_with_errors(@user, :email),
                           placeholder: 'Email'

   - if @user.authorizations.empty?
    = f.password_field :password, class: class_with_errors(@user, :password),
                                  title: title_with_errors(@user, :password),
                                  placeholder: 'Password'

   = f.fields_for :profile do |p|
    = p.hidden_field :username, value: () 
    = p.text_field :place, class: class_with_errors(@user.profile, :place),
                           title: title_with_errors(@user.profile, :place),
                           id: 'profile-place',
                           placeholder: 'Type in your closest city...'
    = p.hidden_field :city_id, id: 'profile_city_id'
    .tip
     E.G. "New York, New York, United States" or "Barcelona, Cataluña, Spain"

    .note
     Ps - We need this information to show you data relevant to your location.
     We don't share it with anyone. If you cannot find your city, please type
     the largest city closest to you.

   = f.submit 'Sign up', class: 'submit'
```

Due to some association issue, I want to fill the value of

```
 p.hidden_field :username, value: ()
```

with name and id.

For example if user fill name as 'Name Surname' and user id is '55' then username should be NameSurname55.

Please suggest code. Thanks in advance

My usercontroller looks like:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout 'land'
  #before_action :set_username

  def create
    params[:user][:profile_attributes].delete(:place)

    super do |resource|
      UserMailer.welcome(resource).deliver

      aroundyoga_user = User.find_by(email: 'aroundyoga@gmail.com')
      resource.follow!(aroundyoga_user) && aroundyoga_user.follow!(resource)

      RegistrationWorker.perform_async(resource.id)
    end
  end

  protected

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      welcome_path
    end

end
```

Comment: Either do it in the backend or just use JS to change the value of your hidden field.

Comment: @YanFoto can u suggest how to do it in backend?

Comment: Fetch the values from `params` in your contoller and concat them?

Comment: @YanFoto I am trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `:username` input is hidden, so I assume user should not be able to edit username. Then you better remove this field from form at all and do all logic on server-side:

```
def create
  params[:user][:profile_attributes].delete(:place)

  super do |resource|
    # Next 2 lines
    resource.profile.username = resource.name.gsub(/\s+/, "") + resource.id.to_s
    resource.profile.save

    UserMailer.welcome(resource).deliver

    aroundyoga_user = User.find_by(email: 'aroundyoga@gmail.com')
    resource.follow!(aroundyoga_user) && aroundyoga_user.follow!(resource)

    RegistrationWorker.perform_async(resource.id)
  end
end
```

**Edit**: updated code according to information you provided. @pkrawat1 solution is better.

Comment: username is field of profile model. And I have added controller in question check

Comment: what does this line mean- ' super do |resource|' ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your profile model

```
before_create :generate_username

def generate_username
  self.username = self.user.name.underscore + self.user.id.to_s
end
```

Comment: This is not going to work for new object since they have no ID yet.

Comment: @YanFoto yes its not working because they have no id

Comment: Try `before_save` then. User.profile is saved to DB after `user.id` is obtained, so this code should work.

Comment: Hi @YanFoto, since i work on mongoid all the time, i forgot that in active records id's are only generated after the record is saved.

Comment: hey @glyuck, can we use after_save callback and update the attribute, becuse then i would have the id that i need.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid revealing IDs to the public, but If you insist:

Creating an object from `params` in the controller is as easy as writing

```
mo = MyObject.new params[my_object]
```

in your controller. If you need to change some attributes you would just do the following:

```
mo.name = mo.name + mo.id
```

remember that in both cases you have to call `save` to persist changes.

The biggest difficulty in your case is that if the user hasn't been persisted yet (i.e. it's a new object created using `User.new`) it hasn't been assigned an ID yet. But there's also an answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755622/ruby-on-rails-how-to-get-activerecord-to-show-the-next-id-last-1/)

The easiest way might be:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :update_name

  def update_name
    name = name + id
    save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have used accept_nested_attributes in background.

so may be you can use callback in profile model like:

```
after_create: update_profile_username

def update_profile_username
  username = user.name + user.id
  save
end
```