# Fill Hash with nil values if no values given

Tags: ruby, magic-square, ruby-hash

I have these arrays:

```
positions = [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3]] 
values = [[15, 15, 15], [7, 7]]
keys = [1, 4]
```

I need to create a hash whose keys are from `keys` and the values are from `values`. Values must be at indices defined in `positions. If no index is defined,`nil` should be added to that index.

The three arrays contain the same number of elements; `keys` has two elements, `values` two, and `positions` two. So it's ok.

Expected output:

```
hash = {1=>[15, 15, 15, nil], 4=>[nil, nil, 7, 7]}
```

Comment: Show what have you tried so far.

Comment: Does the first value have a nil at the end because the biggest index found in all the positions is 3?

Comment: @Зелёный Its a bit difficult to show. I just extracted those three arrays (keys, values, positions) from the previous data and now stuck on this part. My tries were something like `Hash[keys.zip values values.values_at(positions) ]` I know its nonsense, I just pasted the idea..

Comment: @adubogdan, yes, biggest index is 3.

Comment: @Andrey Deineko, pretty hard to explain, but these nil values will indicate me where is needed data in other array of arrays (in 2d array)...

Comment: @adubogdan and that biggest index I keep in a variable (it might change)

Comment: I have a feeling that it's worth showing your initial problem (or at least one-two steps before you got here).

Comment: @Andray Deineko - have fun! You asked for it

Comment: Link to definition of the magic square problem, perhaps?

Comment: I have no link to it. Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square . I need to find a "Multiplicative magic squares" in the given input (*$inputs* array in my case)

Comment: I believe I understand how the value of the key `4` was calculated, but I have no idea how the value of `1` was obtained. Can you please explain that?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, I am away for few hours, but if i got you right, these all are calculated in row_sums(arr) method. Later i generated hash which holds  indexes of relevant values and generated hash that holds only those relevant values. Hope i made it clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the zippery begin  (answer to the original question):

```
row_size = positions.flatten.max.next

rows = positions.zip(values).map do |row_positions, row_values|
  row = Array.new(row_size)
  row_positions.zip(row_values).each_with_object(row) do |(position, value), row|
    row[position] = value
  end
end

keys.zip(rows).to_h # => {1=>[15, 15, 15, nil], 4=>[nil, nil, 7, 7]}
```

Comment: As a public service, please consider adding a sentence at the beginning that states the question you are answering. :-)

Comment: Any reason you use `.next` instead of ` + 1`?

Comment: @EricDuminil, generally, I use `+ 1` only if I was already writing some formula `x * y - z + 1`. It's a bit weird mixing English explanations (aka method calls/chains) with math notations (aka operations `+` and numbers `1`) and vice versa. But it's a minor thingy and very much opinion based.

Comment: Okay. It might cause confusion with `Enumerator#next` though. ` + 1` is less ambiguous IMHO.

Comment: “It's a bit weird mixing English explanations (aka method calls/chains) with math notations”—use `positions.flatten.max.public_send(:+, 1)` :)

Comment: @EricDuminil, there is also `String#next`. The idea is that there are many *?nextable?* things in Ruby, just like there are many things you can add `1` to. You have to be aware what is the concept behind the thing you are *?nexting?*. But if you prefer, you can use `#succ` instead.

Comment: to me `next` here is perfectly Rubyish :)

Comment: An alternative would be `row_size = positions.flatten.max + 1 # Believe me, I'm a nerd!` ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil, apparently using `#next` is [57 / 11 times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17523916/2423164) better than + 1. (:

Comment: @ndn: Thanks for the laugh. It's also -57/31 better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest.. but works :P

```
max = positions.flatten.max + 1
pv = positions.zip(values).map { |o| o.transpose.to_h }
h = {}
pv.each_with_index do |v, idx|
  h[keys[idx]] = Array.new(max).map.with_index { |_, i| v[i] }
end

# h
# {1=>[15, 15, 15, nil], 4=>[nil, nil, 7, 7]}
```

or if you prefer a more compressed but less readable one..

```
keys.zip(positions.zip(values).map { |o| o.transpose.to_h }).reduce({}) do |h, (k, v)|
  h[k] = Array.new(max).map.with_index { |_, i| v[i] }
  h
end
```

Comment: A number of elements is not strictly limited to `4`.

Comment: That was not mentioned in the original question, but it's fixed now. Just need to take the highest index in positions. And actually, in one of the comments, the author also mentioned the highest index IS 3. @mudasobwa

Comment: Highest index IS `3` ≠ a number of elements is strictly limited to `4`. BTW, using such constants hardcoded is a code smell.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many elements there are in this scenario though. And I absolutely think it's fine if it was extracted as a constant and if it is a recognized and accepted constraint of the system, which also removes the need to re-calculate the max every time.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
nils = (0..positions.flatten.max).zip([nil]).to_h
keys.zip(positions, values).group_by(&:shift).map do |k, v|
  [k, nils.merge(v.shift.reduce(&:zip).to_h).values]
end.to_h
#⇒ {1=>[15, 15, 15, nil], 4=>[nil, nil, 7, 7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_hash = {}

keys.each_with_index do |key, index|

    new_hash[key] = Array.new(positions.flatten.max + 1)
    value_array = values[index] 
    position_array = positions[index] 
    position_array.each_with_index.map { |element, i| new_hash[key][element] = value_array[i]} 
end 
new_hash
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: A number of elements is not strictly limited to `4`.