# Is it possible to get the ID of the row being inserted *in the statement*?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to have the image I'm uploading have the ID of the row it belongs to as the name (e.g. `42.jpg`) to ensure uniqueness.

Is it possible to get this in the middle of the query? Or do I have to get the ID after then update the row?

Comment: If it is always equal to `id` - why to store it twice?

Comment: If you want uniqueness, use a GUID.

Comment: Are you storing a BLOB or path to the filename?

Comment: This probably isn't a great idea.

Comment: possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/a/1405500/3574819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first insert an empty row (with a `null` image and filename.)  You can retrieve the last inserted ID with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

After that, you can update the row with the image and the file name based on the ID.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is AUTO_INCREMENT column in the table you're inserting... no, the automatically assigned value is not available during statement execution. And the value isn't available when a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger is fired.

The value assigned to the row is only available *after* the INSERT statement completes.

Immediately following a successful insert, `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` (equivalent library function) can retrieve the value assigned.

As another option, you could consider emulating an Oracle sequence object, using a separate table with an AUTO_INCREMENT column, and LAST_INSERT_ID. If you get that as a unique id before you do the INSERT, you could supply the value in the INSERT.