# Finding the next available value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a database table `products` with the following columns.

```
ID | segment_key | segment_value
1  |  Mo         | 1
2  |  Mo         | 3
4  |  Jo         | 1
5  |  Jo         | 2
6  |  Ta         | 1
```

For any given key I need to find the next available segment_value for me to record in the same table.

ie. for the following `segment_key` list, the expected outputs are

```
Mo -> 2
Jo -> 3
Ta -> 2
Ji -> 1
```

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405393/finding-the-next-available-id-in-mysql) but I cannot seem to get the right output.

This is my failed attempt.

```
SELECT t1.segment_value 
FROM products t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM products t2
    WHERE t2.segment_value = t1.segment_value + 1 and t2.segment_key='Mo' and t2.is_active=1
)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Where is `Ji` value in your sample data`segment_key`?

Comment: `SELECT t1.segment_key,t1.segment_value+1 FROM products t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products t2 WHERE t2.segment_key=t1.segment_key and t2.segment_value=t1.segment_value+1) group by t1.segment_key`

Comment: @D-Shih Ji is an unknown key, for that I can expect a 0 or Null.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use *CTE RECURSIVE* to get the gap of all values. then do `CROSS JOIN` fill in the gap of value from each `segment_key`.

Final using `OUTER JOIN` and filter `segment_key IS NULL` which represent the gap of values

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS(
  SELECT MIN(segment_value) val,MAX(segment_value) + 1 max_val
  FROM products
  UNION ALL
  SELECT val + 1 ,max_val
  FROM CTE c
  WHERE  val + 1 <= max_val
)  
SELECT c.segment_key,MIN(val) segment_value 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT val,segment_key
  FROM CTE 
  CROSS JOIN products
) c
LEFT JOIN products p
ON c.val = p.segment_value AND c.segment_key = p.segment_key
WHERE p.segment_key IS NULL
GROUP BY c.segment_key;
```

| segment_key | segment_value |
| --- | --- |
| Mo | 2 |
| Jo | 3 |
| Ta | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fuYE8UacZF1ExVweNsceBV/0)