# Return Last ID (IDENTITY) On Insert row VB.NET MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, identity

```
Dim insert_coupon_query As String = ("INSERT INTO qa_discountcoupons (id, status_code) VALUES (AUTO_INCREMENT_ID, 5)")
                Dim cmd_query As New MySqlCommand(insert_coupon_query, objConn)
                Dim cmd_result As Integer = CInt(cmd_query.ExecuteScalar())
```

I want to return the AUTO_INCREMENT value of the current insert, and show in a msgbox.

Comment: Are you actually passing an ID as the query suggests?  Or is it really an auto-increment?  In MySQL you can select `LAST_INSERT_ID` to get the last auto-incremented ID in a transaction.

Comment: No, THe id is generated by MySQL, i only pass the status code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use an double Query and use the function [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) After run your first query to get the last current query:

```
Dim insert_coupon_query As String = ("INSERT INTO qa_discountcoupons (status_code) VALUES (5); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
                Dim cmd_query As New MySqlCommand(insert_coupon_query, objConn)
                Dim cmd_result As Integer = CInt(cmd_query.ExecuteScalar())

                MsgBox(cmd_result)
```

Comment: Never thought we could use a double query in vb.net sql statement.  It helps to get the auto-increment number from ID column.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party but after

```
cmd_query.ExecuteScalar()
MsgBox(cmd_query.LastInsertedId)
```

Produces the last insert id.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the AUTO_INCREMENT value for a table through a [MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933565/get-auto-increment-value-with-mysql-query) and then show that in your MsgBox