# Obtain last inserted id in vb.net from a mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I found the answer that said you could return the id with a double query but mine comes up null. Any ideas? The method did work before I switched the bottom line to return an integer instead of just executing the query.

```
Public Function insertDynamicQuery(ByVal strTable As String, ByVal strParameters As String(), ByVal strParameterValues As String()) As Integer
    Dim intParameterCount As Integer = strParameters.Count() - 1
    Dim strQuery As String = "INSERT INTO " + strTable + " ("
    For i = 0 To intParameterCount
        strQuery += strParameters(i)
        If i < intParameterCount Then
            strQuery += ", "
        End If
    Next
    strQuery += ") VALUES ("
    For i = 0 To intParameterCount
        strQuery += "@insertparameter" + i.ToString()
        If i < intParameterCount Then
            strQuery += ", "
        End If
    Next
    strQuery += ");"
    strQuery += " SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM " + strTable + ";"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, _DBConnection)
    For k = 0 To intParameterCount
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insertparameter" + k.ToString, strParameterValues(k))
        '  Console.WriteLine("@insertparameter" + k.ToString + "//" + strParameterValues(k))
    Next
    Return CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
End Function
```

Comment: The `insert` works?

Comment: `MySqlCommand.LastInsertedId`  That insert isntdoing anything to map the values to the proper columns.

Comment: I added the Last_Insert_ID() line and added the return line. The method worked fine to only insert an entry. I was following the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791156/return-last-id-identity-on-insert-row-vb-net-mysql

Comment: Your way worked great, thanks! Not sure why the other question is different but thank you.