# MySQL insert ID ascending

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

I want to insert user IDs into a table in ascending order. So I want to make something like this:

`insert last insert+1`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Take a look at 'auto_increment' for your primary key.

Comment: Try this.

SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='your_table_name' AND table_schema = DATABASE();

OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933565/get-auto-increment-value-with-mysql-query

Answer (score 1):

In phpmyadmin, there is an option the 'check' for a field being `auto_incremented`. You don't have to insert the ID, as it automatically does it on insertion of other data.

Please note that the ID column NEEDS to be a primary key!!!