# How to generate unique id in mysql before insert?

Tags: mysql

I want to generate unique id in mysql before insert.
Which concept is better for this .
pls tell suggesstion to me.

I want to give auto increment with string....
Like create SKU id

Answer (score 6):

You could just have a primary key which is set on auto-increment, to get a unique id each time. This is done most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the primary key as auto-increment and this will work for you...

Comment: Then before saving next record get the last id from DB, increase it by one( this will make new Id) and then save it to DB again :)

Comment: Auto-increment works with int type, so you cant use it with strings... so you have to do this manually

Comment: MySql does not allow auto-increment with Strings, Or you need to write some inner queries/procedures for that ...

Answer (score 0):

You can [get the auto increment value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933565/get-auto-increment-value-with-mysql-query) like that, though, making the column [A_I](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) will increase your ID every insert.

Comment: Check out the first link for that.