# Have field take value of another field when not explicitly given new value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in this format:

```
 id | ....... | other_id
-------------------------
  1 | ....... |    5     
  2 | ....... |    2
```

Basically, when the form is submitted, sometimes there will be a value for `other_id` in the form, and the insertion of the new row goes as normal. However, if there is no value given for `other_id`, I want its value to come from `id`. The issue is that `id` is the auto incrementing id, so the actual value of `id` is unknown until it's actually inserted into the table.

Is there a way to dynamically do this with SQL itself, without having to run additional queries afterward?

Comment: fast answer NO, tricky answer check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933565/get-auto-increment-value-with-mysql-query

Comment: @YourCommonSense I assumed I had a syntax issue but I guess not! I undeleted

Answer (score 1):

You can use a insertion trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo AFTER INSERT ON TABLENAME FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.other_id IS NULL THEN
   SET NEW.other_id := NEW.id;
END IF;;
```

Comment: Thanks - after modifying to correct field names, I get this error in trying to create the trigger: `#1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger ` Am I supposed to be using `NEW`?

Answer (score 0):

@jh314 is almost right. Just change AFTER INSERT to BEFORE INSERT

Comment: Well, the id doesn't have a value before the insert.

Comment: aka if I changed this to a before insert, it would have a value of 0.