# How can I count the amount of rows in a column in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, count, rows

As the title states, I want to count the amount of rows in a column using a SQL query in PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to get table row count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933565/most-efficient-way-to-get-table-row-count)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the number of rows, you can use the `count(*)` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table
```

If you want the number of values (i.e., excluding `null`s), you can use `count` on the column:

```
SELECT COUNT(my_column) FROM my_table
```

If you want the number of **different** values, you can add the `distinct` keyword:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT my_column) FROM my_table
```